# How to fix 'TypeError: move_to_right() missing 1 required positional argument: 'learner''

Tags: python

I am new to Python so forgive me if this is a rookie mistake. My objective is to have two list boxes and when I double click an item in the list on the left, it removes it then adds it to the list on the right, and vise versa. The issue I am currently having is that I am 'missing 1 required positional argument:'learner''.

I don't quite understand why I am receiving this error as I believe I am already giving the parameter 'learner'. As shown in my code 'learner' is used within the brackets of my function.

```
def move_to_right(self, learner):  
    self.buttonHandler(learner)  

for learner in concatstring:  
    filteredlistbox.insert("end", learner)  
    filteredlistbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda: self.move_to_right(learner))  
move_to_right(learner)
```

I would expect this to run smoothly, as in my eyes I am giving it the required parameter. But it's likely I am missing something that I do not realise.

Comment: Is this inside a `class`…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your real code is like below:

```
class T:
    def move_to_right(self, learner):
        self.buttonHandler(learner)

        for learner in concatstring:
            filteredlistbox.insert("end", learner)
            filteredlistbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda: self.move_to_right(learner))
        move_to_right(learner)
```

The last line is the issue, and it should be `self.move_to_right(learner)`